# Matlab: Convert number to string (with zero-padding AND decimal precision)

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, the `num2str` command converts numbers to strings.

A format input is allowed which permits the user the number format,
including options for zero-padding and precision.

Is there a way to create a string which zero-pads the number to the left
AND permits specified decimal precision?

I'm not getting results which demonstrate this:

### Examples of Problem

Input:
`num2str(1.2,'%04f')`
Output:
1.200000

Input:
`num2str(1.2,'%04.f')`
Output:
0001

Input:
`num2str(1.2,'%04.2f')`
Output:
1.20

Note that zero-padding only occurs in a very specific format.

### Desired behavior

Input:
`num2str(1.2,'%04.2f')`
Output:
0001.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:

```
num2str(1.2,'%07.2f')
```

the number befor the `.` is the **total** number of digits + the `.`.

So `7.2` means: 7 total characters, from them 2 are after the `.`.